# JavaScript - console.log shows list, on access gives undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-realtime-database, undefined

**Context**

In my current application, a chrome extension, all websites visitations are logged and added into Firebase, from where using a function it gets a list of objects of the sites visited on the current day.

**Problem**

Now from those objects I had planned to extract the unique names into a list, which poses a bit of problem because the list which holds these objects doesn't seem to 'exist'. When I console.log it out, it appears as >[] !'Value below was evaluated just now' and then shows the values of those items.

However when I try to access them using an index, it shows *undefined*. Even when running the debugger it seems to give an empty list for some reason, yet as mentioned before a normal console.log of the list gives the excpected results.

**Sample code**

```
function Master() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    let that = this;

    this.http_usage = this.get_http();
    this.https_usage = this.get_https();
    this.todays_usage = this.get_today_sites();

    this.site_names = [];
    console.log(this.todays_usage); 

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request.message);
        if (request.message === "hello") {
            sendResponse({farewell: [that.http_usage.length, that.https_usage.length]});
        }
    });

    this.init();
}

get_today_sites: function () {
    let content = [];

    let start = new Date();
    start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    start = start.getTime();

    let end = new Date();
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    end = end.getTime();

    let ref = firebase.database().ref('websites/');
    ref.orderByChild("time").startAt(start).endAt(end).once('value', function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (snapshot) {
            content.push(snapshot.val());
        })
    });
    return content;
},
```

**console.log(this.todays_usage)**

```
>[]
0:Object
    protocol:"https:"
    time: 1496523823397
    time_spent: 17
    url:"www.google.ee"
    __proto__:
1:Object
    ....
157:Object
    ....
```

**console.log(this.todays_usage[0])**

*undefined*

Comment: firebase is *asynchronous* so `todays_usage` gets its contents after Master() is finished.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it possible to turn asynchronity off? I'm getting data using once instead of on anyway.

Comment: Rework the code to properly utilize asynchronous model.